# set view position by element (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any easy way how to set Y position of the screen by the element?
Tried to do with scrolling but didn't make wanted effect, so maybe setting screen view position would do the trick.

have a div with string:

Function is in use with elementor (wordpress) toggle tabs which generating anchor links for tabs and they making a trick which opens exact tab by link.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            setTimeout(function(){
            var current = window.location.href;
            var current = current.split('#tab');
            if(current.length>1) {  
                 $('.elementor-tab-title').removeClass('elementor-active');
                 $('.elementor-tab-title[data-tab="'+current[1]+'"]').addClass('elementor-active');
                 $('.elementor-tab-content').hide();
                 $('.elementor-tab-content[data-tab="'+current[1]+'"]').show();
             }
            }, 200);

        $('.elementor-tab-title[data-tab]').click(function(){
            var current_location = window.location.href;
            current_location = current_location.split('#');
            window.location = current_location[0]+'#tab'+$(this).attr('data-tab');
            
        })
        
    })
    
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var current = window.location.href
        var current = current.split('#tab')
        if (current.length > 1) {
            showAndScrollToTab($, current)
        }
    }, 200);
    // change the browser url according to selected tab
    $('.elementor-tab-title[data-tab]').click(function () {
        var current_location = window.location.href;
        current_location = current_location.split('#')
        window.location = current_location[0] + '#tab' + $(this).attr('data-tab')
    })
    // activate tab also from anchor link in the same page
    $('a').on('click', function () {
        var anchorUrl = $(this).attr('href')
        var anchor = anchorUrl.split('#tab')
        if (anchor.length > 1) {
            showAndScrollToTab($, anchor)
        }
    })
})
    function showAndScrollToTab($, current) {
        // adding class
        $('.elementor-tab-title').removeClass('elementor-active')
        $('.elementor-tab-title[data-tab="' + current[1] + '"]').addClass('elementor-active')
        
        // scroll to
        var customOffset = '20';  
        $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
            scrollTop: $('.elementor-tab-title[data-tab="' + current[1] + '"]').closest('.elementor-widget-container').offset().top - customOffset            }, 1000)
    }</script>
```

Html in use for toggle tab headings:

```
<div class="elementor-toggle-item">
                    <div id="elementor-tab-title-2287" class="elementor-tab-title elementor-active" data-tab="7" role="tab" aria-controls="elementor-tab-content-2287">
```

How to modify the function for making device screen view top is 40px to the `.elementor-tab-title[data-tab="' + current[1] + '"]` div? Is it possible to adjust offset from div element to top by device (mobile, tablet, desktop)?
Any other solutions are welcome how to do that!

[image]

Comment: can you please share more  code like js with html . i will test this :-)

Comment: How about CSS: `position: fixed; top: 40px;`?

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 - This function in use with toggle tabs, not the only one element.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: Added more code, I'd equal question to the "How make screen view in the center of the element after click", it's same way probably. After link click - need to adjust user screen position 20px from top (of his screen) to the element in shown